# iOS Constraints. How to set image view height ration equal to image ratio by constraints?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, constraints

I've image view with equal width constraint and aspect fit. I need to resize height to the same ration that image has by using constraints is it possible?

Is now:

[image]

I need something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use aspect ratio and it will resize using the same proportion for both width and height

[image]

Comment: Yes but aspect ration set proportion as it is now, but what if image will change ratio? I need that image view height take minimum height.

Comment: aspect-fit is using there, but it move image to the center of image view